# ManyToOne and OneToMany issue Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello I've a big problem with entities relationship.

I have two entities
Users and TipoUtenti

```
class Users
{    
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TipoUtenti" inversedBy="utenti")
 **/
protected $usersus;
...

class TipoUtenti
{

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Users", mappedBy="usersus")
 */
protected $utenti;

public function __construct()
{
$this->$utenti = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

If I look at Profile query I saw:

```
SELECT 
t0.name AS name1, 
t0.email AS email2, 
t0.id_tipo_utente AS id_tipo_utente10, 
t0.citta_id AS citta_id14, 
t0.id AS id15 
FROM 
Users t0
```

and no join in query.

What's the problem?

Comment: What code do u use to fetch list of users?

Comment: $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MassaggiBundle:Users');
    $users = $repository->findAll();   

    foreach ($users as $user) {
    $cittas[]=$user->getCittaId();
  
    }

Comment: Doctrine doesn't load child entities by default on `->find*` calls. If you want get entity with mapped ones you should use `DQL` or `QueryBuilder` with `left join` to show doctrine what associations you want to load.

Comment: try (if your mapping und method names a correct): `foreach($users as $user) { $cittas[] = $user->getUsersus()->getCittald(); }`

Comment: please show also the related getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the solution [Many-To-Many, Bidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

```
 /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_groups") // this is what you've forgotten
     **/
```

Otherwise, try to use [DQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) and write your own query

Comment: I trued it but the query in Profile is the same